# Pipe Find command "stderr" to a command

Tags: unix, find, pipe, io-redirection

Hi I have a peculiar problem and I'm trying hard to **find** (pun intended) a solution for it.

```
$> find ./subdirectory -type f 2>>error.log
```

I get an error, something like, "find: ./subdirectory/noidea: Permission denied" from this command and this will be redirected to **error.log**.

Is there any way I can pipe the *stderr* to another command before the redirection to **error.log**?

I want to be able to do something like

```
$> find ./subdirectory -type f 2 | sed "s#\(.*\)#${PWD}\1#" >> error.log
```

where I want to pipe only the **stderr** to the **sed** command and get the whole path of the *find command error*.

I know piping doesn't work here and is probably not the right way to go about.

My problem is I need both the *stdout* and *stderr* and the both have to be processed through different things simultaneously.

EDIT:
Ok. A slight modification to my problem.

Now, I have a shell script, **solve_problem.sh**

In this shell script, I have the following code

```
ErrorFile="error.log"
for directories in `find ./subdirectory -type f 2>> $ErrorFile`
do
    field1=`echo $directories | cut -d / -f2`
    field2=`echo $directories | cut -d / -f3`
done
```

Same problem but inside a shell script. The "find: ./subdirectory/noidea: Permission denied" error should go into **$ErrorFile** and *stdout* should get assigned to the variable *$directories*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe stderr and stdout simultaneously - idea taken from [this post](http://fenski.pl/tips-tricks/):

```
(find /boot | sed s'/^/STDOUT:/' ) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | sed 's/^/STDERR:/'
```

Sample output:

```
STDOUT:/boot/grub/usb_keyboard.mod
STDERR:find: `/boot/lost+found': Brak dostępu
```

Bash redirections like `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` swaps stderr and stdout.

I would modify your sample script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ErrorFile="error.log"
(find ./subdirectory -type f 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | sed "s#^#${PWD}: #" >> $ErrorFile) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | while read line; do
    field1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d / -f2)
    ...
done
```

Notice that I swapped stdout & stderr twice.

Small additional comment - look at `-printf` option in find manual page. It might be useful to you.

Comment: This is a useful technique, but care should be taken.  In particular, you now have the error messages of find being written to stdout with the prefix "STDERR:", and the stdout of find going to stderr with the prefix "STDOUT:"   That is potentially confusing.

Comment: @kupson: Very handy solution indeed. But I'm not sure it'll work in my scenario.
I tried something like
`(find ./subdirectory/ -type f) 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | sed "s?^\(find: \)\(.*\)?\1${PWD}/\2?" >> $ErrorFile` but this didn't work for me. The errors get redirected to the log file the way I want but the _stdout_ doesn't get assigned to the variable in the for loop (I've updated my problem)

Comment: @latestVersion I would use 'while' loop in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so that the following command in the pipe gets it as its input, then you can use `2>&1`.

For more information, please have a look at the [all about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) how-to.

Edit: Even if you need to edit pass `stdout` further in the pipe, you can use `sed` to filter error messages and write them to a file:

```
$ find . -type f 2>&1 | sed '/^find:/{
> w error.log
> d
> }'
```

In this example:

- in `find` command `stderr` is redirected to `stdout`
- in `sed` command errors from `find` that match a regular expression are written to a file (`w error.log`) and removed from output (`d`).
- any command in the pipeline following the pipeline will received the output from `find`.

Note: This will work as lon as all the error messages from `find` start with `find:`. Otherwise, the regular expression in `sed` should be modified to properly match all cases.

Comment: Piping itself is out of question in my case as I want the **stderr** going through the "sed" command and the **stdout** going through a different set of commands in my script.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works. Maybe you can help me understand what's happening here.
Also would I be able to substitute in the `sed` command??

Comment: I've edited the explanatino to make it clearer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (on bash), which appears to work:

```
find ./subdirectory -type f 2> >(sed "s#\(.*\)#${PWD}\1#" >> error.log)
```

This does the following:

1. `2>` redirects stderr to
2. `>(...)` a process substitution (running sed, which appends to error.log)

Comment: This solution works on the command line. But I got stuck with syntax error when I tried it in a shell script. Anyway you can help me out on this?

Comment: @latestVersion: I just tried the line as I posted it (on bash 4.2.20), and it appears to work. note that there _must_ be a space after `2>` or you will get a syntax error. (actually, there needs to be a space before `>(...)` but it's the same thing in this case.)